# What is wrong in my code? Swapping first and last letter of a word, using method replace

Tags: python, python-3.x

Given any word, swap the first and the last letter's position then return the new string. If that is a one-letter word, return the word. I'm aware the fastest way to do this is to use slicing, or join but I want to try a new approach using replace.

```
def front_back(any_string):
  if len(any_string) <= 1:
    return any_string
  else:
    temp = any_string.replace(any_string[0],list(any_string)[-1])
    final_str = temp.replace(temp[-1],list(any_string)[0])
  print(final_str)
  
front_back('line')
```

Instead of "einl", it returns "linl".

Comment: `.replace()` is an utterly inappropriate tool for this job.  How could it possibly work if the first/last characters of the word also appeared elsewhere in the word?

Comment: Thank you for your input. The way I initially understood it was that I was pointing the program to go to the character at that exact index and replace it with the other character. But obviously that is not the right way of thinking.

Answer (score 0):

```
def front_back(any_string: str) -> str:
    if len(any_string) < 2:
        return any_string
    else:
        return any_string[-1] + any_string[1:-1] + any_string[0]


print(front_back('line'))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def front_back(any_string):
    if len(any_string) <= 1:
        return any_string
    else:
        temp = any_string.replace(any_string[0],list(any_string)[-1]) #1
        final_str = temp.replace(temp[-1],list(any_string)[0]) #2
    print(final_str)

front_back('line')
#Instead of "einl", it returns "linl"
it is because 
any_string="Line"
#1 when you replace "L"(any_string(0)) with "e"(any_string(-1))
then the value becomes "eine" and it stores in temp.

#2. you are trying to replace the last "e" which is placed at any_string(-1)
here what happens is you have two "e" characters in "eine" that is in temp 
variable.
when you try to replace "L" in place of "e". it replaces both "e" characters.
the starting "e" character and ending "e" character.making it "linl"
```

Comment: Thank you. The way I initially understood it was that I was pointing the program to go to the character at that exact index and replace ONLY the character having that index. But obviously that is not the right way of thinking